# How to Wait the Observable to Finish Before the Subscribe

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic2, rxjs, observable

I wrote RXJS operators to get an array of locations.

this is my code:

```
return  O$ = this.db.list(`UserPlaces/${this.authData.auth.auth.currentUser.uid}`, {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'deleted',
      equalTo: false
    }
  })
  .map((locations: any) => {
    return locations.map(location => {
      return location.$key;
    });
  }).switchMap(ids => {
    return ids.map(id => {
      return this.db.object(`Devices/${id}`)
    });
  })
  .flatMap((x: any) => {
    return x;
  })
  .map((x:any)=>{
     if(!x.deleted){
      return x;
    }
  })
  .scan((acc:any, item) => [...acc, item],[])
  .do(console.log)
```

The given array is filled by sequential  way:

```
[{}] --> [{},{}] --> [{},{},{}] --> [{},{},{},{},...]
```

What I need is getting the fully array directly:

```
[{},{},{},{},...]
```

I tried to use the forkJoin but doesn't work :

```
return Observable.forJoin(O$) //but doesn't work.
```

Any help to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the question is how do you know when you want to emit the array if the source never completes. It could be when `[{},{}]` or is it when `[{},{}, {}]`? Maybe you could use `auditTime()`? http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime

Answer (score 0):

You subscribe to it using the full power of the `subscribe` method and wait until the `complete` callback is called or an error is thrown:

```
const o$ = (...) // your final observable
let array = null;
o$.subscribe({
    next: value => array = value,
    complete: () => {
        // the operation behind the observable completed. No more values
        // will be yielded. 'array' contains the final values
    },
    error: (error) => {
        // there was an error. No more values will be yielded
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for you replying,, I after I used your way the subscribe is not working at all ,, in the complete and in the error stage

Comment: Which subscribe is not working? I don't understand. You were already subscribing to the observable? In your code I don't see any subscription.

Comment: after wrote your way ,, I loged the array inside the complete part nothing appear and I loged the error inside the error stage and nothing appear

Comment: Can you post the code where you are subscribing to the observable?

Answer (score 0):

Change .scan to reduce()

```
.map((x:any)=>{
 if(!x.deleted){
  return x;
}
})
  .reduce((acc:any, item) => {
     acc.push(item)
     return acc
},[])
```

Comment: thank you for your replying, after I used the reduce op. the subscribe is not working

Comment: Maybe move do() to upper line to debug

Comment: reduce doesn't emit anything because the source observable did not complete. It's the same for forkJoin. You will have to complete your source observable before that.

Comment: Yes, i have assumed it will complete. We will need to know more about the db api